# How to Display Icons on the Autodesk forge viewer without using an extension

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I want to display some icons ( ex : exclamation mark ) on the viewer. My scenario is retrieving some data and display an icon on a particular object accordingly.
I could not find any documentation regarding this but found a [sample code](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/placing-custom-markup-dbid) which uses an extension and then having icons as markups. Is there anyway to do a similar kind of operation without using an extension ??

Thank you!!

Comment: the simple solution would be u can take the position of your asset and then u can send this position to your HTML like this position would be relative u would be able to show anything over the asset

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [sprites](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/dataviz/v1/developers_guide/examples/create_sprite_style/) tutorial.

We`re also covering different options for labels in [this](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/how-do-you-add-labels-forge-viewer) series of blogs.